# What are the various files created when compiling linux device driver?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have very basic question. When we create a driver using makefile, we see a number of files created as

1. Module.symvers
2. .mod.c
3. built-in.o
4. .mod.o
5. .o
6. modules.order
7. .ko

So far I'm only interested in *.ko file and not concerned with any other file. But still i wanna know about other files, what are they used for?
Please reply

Comment: well you need to read this "modules.txt" in kernel source tree they have explained everything about module building or you can go here . http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation pointed in the comment and some other sources ([1](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt), [2](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt) and [3](http://tuxthink.blogspot.fr/2011/03/overview-of-compiling-kernel-modules.html)):

1. Module.symvers - *"Module.symvers contains a list of all exported symbols from a kernel build."*
2. .mod.c - *"is a file that basically contains the information about the module (Version information etc)"*
3. built-in.o - This file is not related to kernel modules but instead normal kernel build. *"Kbuild compiles all the $(obj-y) files.  It then calls "$(LD) -r" to merge these files into one built-in.o file. built-in.o is later linked into vmlinux by the parent Makefile"*
4. .mod.o - objcet files resulting from the compilation of the .mod.c files.
5. .o - object files resulting from the compilation of the module source files.
6. modules.order - *"In case you are compiling multiple modules together, it will list out the order in which the compilation and creation of .ko takes"*
7. .ko - the final kernel module binary that is loaded into the kernel.